# Curl installed with VCPKG won't link properly with CMake

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, libcurl, vcpkg

I'm facing difficulties in correctly linking **LIBCURL** with CMakeLists in VSCode for my C project. Despite successfully installing curl with vcpkg, it still doesn't work.

Could someone provide guidance on setting up the CMakeLists file in VSCode to link **LIBCURL**.

Any assistance, code snippets, or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Here's how my CMakeLists looks so far:**

**Path of VCPKG: C:/vcpkg**

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share")
find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
include_directories("C:\\vcpkg\\installed\\x64-windows\\include\\")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

**Error:**

```
CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:853 (_find_package):Could not find a configuration file for package "CURL" that is compatible
with requested version "".

The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

  C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/curl/CURLConfig.cmake, version: 8.1.2-DEV (64bit)
```

Comment: How do you run `cmake`?

Comment: I'm a newbie at this so IDRK, how VS code does it, but I run cmake by right clicking the CMakeLists.txt and clicking Clean Rebuild All Projects.

Comment: Most likely you build a 32-bit application. Set VS Code cmake plugin for building a 64-bit application, install 32-bit libcurl.

Comment: It seems like CMake does find the Curl config file (CURLConfig.cmake). I complains about the version, but I think that this is a wrong error message (because you don't specify a version, so everything should be accepted). I would tend to agree with @273K: check if you are building a 64-bit application or try to install a 32-bit curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments: You are probably mixing x86 and x64. While your vcpkg has x64 libraries installed your cmake project is somehow set to x86. This might happen if you use e.g. VS 2019 or below  generator or you explicitly requested x86.
Secondly please read the vcpkg manual how to use vcpkg correctly. Manually setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or adding a hardcoded vcpkg paths to `include_directories` is not the correct approach.